# How to set every element in an array to 0

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am learning C++ and one of my practice exercises is to use pointers to set all the elements in an array to 0. I have no idea how to do this by incrementing the pointer to the next position in the array since my IDE log said that comparison between *int* and * is forbidden. I only need a small snippet as an example to help me better understand where i'm going wrong. The array I have created is of type *int* and has a single dimension with 5 elements consisting of 1,2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: Actually using "for (i=0; i< 5; i++) array[i] = 0" you are incrementing the pointer

Comment: For better explanation, check out this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_an_array.htm)

Comment: so far I have  

int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr = arr;


    while (*ptr < arr){
            ptr = 0;
            ++ptr;

    }

Comment: memset? (It *does* use pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for(int *i = &array[0], *end = &array[5]; i != end; i++)
    *i = 0;
```

The code creates a pointer to the start `&array[0]` and a pointer to one position past the end `&array[5]`
Then it steps the pointer through the array, setting each element to zero.
A more advanced concept that is very similar is [iterators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html).

Comment: One can also use calloc to initialise the elements of the array to 0. See Man page of Calloc.

Comment: I did think to myself that using a while loop was a bit off. I couldn't figure out how I would create it in a for loop though, I was sure I'd need a reference at some point but I'm yet to fully understand the syntax properly for things I am new too. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user3806887: A while loop would work fine as well.  Your original code in your comment was quite close, but you'd need to change it to: `int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; int *ptr = arr; int *end = arr+5; while (ptr < end) { *ptr = 0; ++ptr; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::fill, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill, as follows.

```
const size_t dataSize = 10;
int data[dataSize];
std::fill(data, data + dataSize, 0);
```